# What might cause glassfish asadmin.bat start-domain 3.1.1 to exit with code 143?

Tags: glassfish, glassfish-3

I am running glassfish as a windows service created by the asadmin `create-service` command (where it starts with a command something like):

```
c:/xyz/glassfish/bin/asadmin.bat start-domain --verbose --domaindir C:\\xyz\\glassfish\\domains myDomain
```

I started the server then left it running with no further activities (no clients connecting to it, no scheduled task, etc).

After approximately 5hours 30mins it terminated with code 143.

Anyone know what might cause such behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

143 means the process was killed (SIGTERM).

You probably logged out.

Add this to the java line at the end of asadmin.bat

-Xrs

e.g.

%JAVA% -Xrs -jar "%~dp0..\modules\admin-cli.jar" %*

It's also a good idea to add "-Xrs" to the server.  Go to the bin directory of your domain, edit the xml file (it's obvious what to do) and then

```
myDomainService stop 
myDomainService uninstall 
myDomainService install
myDomainService start
```

Comment: If the JVM is run as a service (for example, the servlet engine for a web server), it can receive CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT but should not initiate shutdown since the operating system will not actually terminate the process. To avoid possible interference such as this, the -Xrs command-line option has been added beginning with J2SE 1.3.1. When the -Xrs option is used on Sun's JVM, the JVM does not install a console control handler, implying that it does not watch for or process CTRL_C_EVENT, CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT, CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT, or CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT.

Comment: There are two consequences of specifying -Xrs:

    Ctrl-Break thread dumps are not available.
    User code is responsible for causing shutdown hooks to run, for example by calling System.exit() when the JVM is to be terminated.

Answer (score 0):

143 means the process was killed (SIGTERM).

You probably logged out.

Add this to the java line at the end of asadmin.bat

-Xrs

e.g.

%JAVA% -Xrs -jar "%~dp0..\modules\admin-cli.jar" %*

also add the following line in domain.xml

To set the -Xrs Java VM option, add the following line to the section of the
as-install\domains\domain-name\config\domain.xmlfile that defines Java VM options:

-Xrs

If the Communications Server service is running, stop and restart the service for your changes to become effective.